# Flutter - How to get width of a FlatButton in a horizontal ListView

Tags: flutter

I want to get the width of a FlatButton in an horizontal ListView but i only can get `Width: Infinity`.

I can get width in an isolated FlatButton succesfully, but when the FlatButton is inside of a ListView i cannot, but i don't know why. Could you help me to get the width of a FlatButton when it is inside a ListView?

Thanks.

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {


    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Flutter App'),
      ),
      body: Container(
        height: 70.0,
        child: ListView(
          scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
          children: <Widget>[
            _flatButtonStoreWidth(),
            _flatButtonStoreWidth(),
            _flatButtonStoreWidth(),
            _flatButtonStoreWidth(),
            _flatButtonStoreWidth(),

          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

Widget _flatButtonStoreWidth (){

return FlatButton (
  child: LayoutBuilder(
    builder: (BuildContext context, BoxConstraints constraints) {
      double _width = constraints.maxWidth;
      print('Width: $_width');
      return Text('This is a FlatButton');
    },
  ),
  onPressed: (){},
);

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get width of the object in ListView you are supposed to:

1. Give widget a `GlobalKey`.
2. When build is complete, access the context through the `GlobalKey`.
3. Using `context` you can get size by `context.size`.
4. You can get width from `Size` object.

Following is the working code for your reference:

```
Widget _flatButtonStoreWidth() {
    GlobalKey globalKey = GlobalKey();
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
      double _width = globalKey.currentContext.size.width;
      print('Width: $_width');
    });
    return FlatButton(
      key: globalKey,
      child: Text('This is a FlatButton'),
      onPressed: () {},
    );
  }
```

I hope this helps, in case of any doubt please comment. *In case this this answer helps you please accept and up-vote it.*

Comment: Exactly on the bulleye! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

That's because the ListView with a horizontal axis has an infinite width. You'll have to provide a width for each FlatButton.

FlatButton gets its size from the parent. In this case the parent provides an infinite width. Therefore you should size the button yourself

Comment: But in the real life the width of a FlatButton depends of the width of the text inside it, how can I get the width of the FlatButton once a Text for it is provided? Thanks